# UWP SerialDevice Serial port reads nothing since last update

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I'm currently developping a Mifare Chip reader on our UWP app. I coded a tiny read/write program to test the thing last december and when I came back from holidays it seems that the SerialDevice class doesn't work anymore.

I tested my device on the proprietary software and also in realterm and everything work perfectly. Here's my code :

```
string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM4");
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
if (devices.Count > 0)
{
     DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices[0];
     SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
     Debug.WriteLine(serialDevice);
     serialDevice.BaudRate = 115200;
     serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
     serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
     serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
     serialDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

     DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);
     dataWriter.WriteString("INV\r");
     await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
     dataWriter.DetachStream();
     dataWriter = null;

     DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(serialDevice.InputStream);
     dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
     UInt32 bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
     string test = dataReader.ReadString(bytesRead);
}
```

The code returns no error as usual. But the UnconsumedBufferLength is at 0, bytesRead is also at 0 and test is "".

Is anyone experiencing that kind of problem?
That segment of code was functional few days ago... i don't understand

Comment: I manager to make it work changing :
    UInt32 bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1024);

I don't understand why UnconsumedBufferLength returns 0

Comment: In what device are you running this code?
Did it work before, actually sending and receiving bytes over the serial port?